# Deprecation warning: #apply_finder_options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, deprecated, will-paginate

I get `DEPRECATION WARNING: #apply_finder_options is deprecated.` when trying this in my `user.rb`:

```
def User.search(search, page)
  paginate page: page,
           per_page: 10,
           conditions: ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"],
           order: 'name'
end
```

Called through `UsersController`:

```
def index
  @users = User.search(params[:search], params[:page])
end
```

The pagination is done with the `will_paginate` gem.

What is triggering the warning and how can I fix it? Been trying some googling, but I find the docs not too comprehensive!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you just need to pull the order and conditions options out of the paginate method and use Active Record for that instead:

```
def User.search(search, page)
  order('name').where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%").paginate(page: page, per_page: 10)
end
```