# Undefined Method "apply_finder_options"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an undefined method error 'apply_finder_options'

_question.html.erb and where the error says it is

```
def self.unsolved(params)
    where(solved: false).paginate(page: params[:page], order: 'created_at DESC', per_page: 3)
  end

  def self.search(params)
```

Questions Controller

```
def show
   puts params
   @question = Question.find(params[:id])
   @answer = Answer.new
 end
```

Full Error Stack Trace

```
activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in `method_missing'
activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:99:in `method_missing'
will_paginate (3.0.7) lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb:168:in `paginate'
app/models/question.rb:12:in `unsolved'
app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:6:in `index'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Can you post your full `error stacktrace`?

Comment: Do you have any method called `apply_finder_options` somewhere in your code?

Comment: In any of my controllers?

Comment: What does your error say? Can you post your full error?

Comment: My full error is: "NoMethodError in QuestionsController#index" and "undefined method `apply_finder_options' for #<Question::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fed08551bb0>"

Comment: Can you post your `index` method of your controller?

Comment: def index
    (@)question = Question.new
    @questions = Question.unsolved(params)
  end

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing your `unsolved` method to like this

```
def self.unsolved(params)
  order('created_at DESC').where(solved: false).paginate(page: params[:page],per_page: 3)
end
```

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667615/deprecation-warning-apply-finder-options)**

Comment: exchange def index with your answer?

Comment: @user00000001 Not `index`,replace the `unsolved` method with my answer and check.